# Woocommerce conditionally redirect to cart after clicking "add to cart" button

Tags: wordpress, hook, woocommerce

I'm beginner with woocommerce api. I'm looking for a conditional filter when user click "add to cart". I'd like that it automatically redirect to the checkout for a specific product category. Is that possible?
I already know how to redirect, but it does it for all products.

Answer (score 2):

I found a little code snippets to do so :

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');
function redirect_to_checkout() {
        global $woocommerce;
        //Get product ID
        $product_id = (int) apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['product_id']);
        //Check if product ID is in a certain taxonomy
        if( has_term( 'membership-donations', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
                    //Get cart URL
                    $checkout_url = get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id'));
                    //Return the new URL
                    return $checkout_url;
         };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default option that is build into WooCommerce. You can find the option in the `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Display area`. When the option “Redirect to the cart page after successful addition” is checked it will redirect all users to the cart after adding a product to the cart.